# Trying do post request using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make http post request using python. Also I need `totp` authentication and for this I'm using `pyotp`. For the request I'm using Requests library. But the code doesn't work and I don't know where the mistake is. Do you have ideas? I'm using python 3.5.

This is the code:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import pyotp

totp = pyotp.TOTP('base32secret3232')

url = 'http://3425325325664364345365'

datas = {
"github_url": "https://gist.github.com/323332/333333",
"contact_email": "354353634643@gmail.com"
}

headers = {
'Accept': '*/*',
'Content-Length': '134',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Host': '45654645654756456457547547',}

AUTH = HTTPDigestAuth('57457457447547@gmail.com4575475745745', 'totp')

r = requests.post(url, json = datas, headers = headers, auth = AUTH)

print (r.status_code)
```

This is the error:

[image]

This is the second error:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have a file called `pyotp.py` in your project directory which shadows the library? It's often the cause for the _module ... has no attribute ..._ error.

Comment: What you mean "shadow library"?

Comment: In this context means: hide, override, replace, being found first and imported instead of any other pyotp module. If you `print(pyotp)` right after importing it you should see where it is imported from.

Answer (score 0):

After I read your question 1 more time I've realized that I missed the last part.

I might be wrong because I've never used this package but you are using python 3.5 but `pyotp` only supports 2.7 --> [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyotp)

Comment: Ohhh, how I missed it. I m trying one more time using python 2.7

Comment: I tried and it still doesn`t work. I add the photo of the second mistake to post above.

Answer (score 0):

using python3.5 have you tried the following library? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) 
view below an example:

```
import http.client
from base64 import b64encode

username= username.encode('utf-8')
password=password..encode('utf-8')
separator = (':').encode('utf-8') 

something = b64encode(username+separator+password).decode("ascii")
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % something}

connect = http.client.HTTPSConnection("url") 
response = connect.getresponse() 
print(response.status) #to validate the response code

connect.request('PUT', 'target_REST', headers=headers)
```

you can also add the body i just chose to omit it - HTTPConnection.request(method, url, body=None, headers={})

I hope this porivdes usefull

Comment: it should be post request and I wanna generate four numbers time-based one time password. So, I think it doesn`t fit me.

Comment: you can use POST rather than PUT, this is just for reference purposes. anyways, were you able to find another library, or switched to python versions?